# In the end of "The Reader" does the photo frame owned by the daughter depict "Hanna Schmitz"?

Tags: the-reader

In the scene at the end of *The Reader* where the daughter places the tin can next to a portrait. The lady on the left wearing a dotted skirt seems to resemble "Hanna Schmitz". Isn't it her?

[image: Portait with the Tin can from "Hanna Shmitz" to the surviving daughter]

Comment: Why would she be in that photo? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reader_(2008_film)#Plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the script of *The Reader*:

> INT. ILANA'S HOUSE. DAY
>
> ILANA is standing at the window watching down to the street
> where MICHAEL is walking away. She has the tin in her hand.
> When he's vanished, she turns and goes into her bedroom.
> There on the dressing table, there is a framed photo of ILANA
> with her mother in Germany before the war. She sets the tin
> down beside the photo.

Thanks to BCdotWeb... The photo is of Ilana and her family. Ilana testified against Hanna and the rest of the female guards. Her mother also testified. In the end, Michael gives the tin to Ilana, who sets it next to the photo of her (mostly) lost family.